# Cannot see LeftNavButton or RightNavButton with TabGroup inside NavigationWindow

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile

Cannot see LeftNavButton or RightNavButton with TabGroup inside NavigationWindow.
What should I do to have LeftNavButton visible?

```
<Alloy>
   <NavigationWindow>
       <TabGroup>
          <Tab>
            <Window>

               <LeftNavButton>
                  <Button title="Back" onClick="...." />
               </LeftNavButton>

               .................. 

            </Window>
          </Tab>

          <Tab>
            <Window>

               <LeftNavButton>
                  <Button title="Back" onClick="...." />
               </LeftNavButton>

               .................. 

            </Window>
          </Tab>

       </TabGroup>  
   </NavigationWindow>
</Alloy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the hierarchy of your XML & add one more node of NavigationWindow like this:

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup>
        <Tab>
            <NavigationWindow>
                <Window>
                    <LeftNavButton>
                        <Button title="Back" onClick="...." />
                    </LeftNavButton>
                    .................. 
                </Window>
            </NavigationWindow>
        </Tab>

        <Tab>
            <NavigationWindow>
                <Window>
                    <LeftNavButton>
                        <Button title="Back" onClick="...." />
                    </LeftNavButton>
                    .................. 
                </Window>
            </NavigationWindow>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>  
</Alloy>
```

**TabGroup** is the root node here & it can only have **Tab** as child-nodes. Inside each **Tab** you can put any layout that we normally do in Alloy.

Comment: tabgroup and navigationwindow are exclusive to each other... you cannot have them inside eachother

Comment: @RenePot, yeah.. forgot it that time.. TabGroup automatically uses same animations as NavigationWindow & provides inbuilt window-stack. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest `NavigationWindow` and `tab`, as a Tab is already a navigationwindow... TabGroup needs to be topmost element.

If you want to open a tabgroup inside a navigationwindow because of UX flow... you'll need to rethink the flow, as in, open the TabGroup so it looks like it is inside it (using animations), but it actually isn't technically.